# Как добавить дополнительный IP адрес на DigitalOcean?

Tags: ip

Как создать дополнительные *ip*-адреса для одного *дроплета*?

В настройках аккаунта не нашёл подходящего инструмента.

Answer (score 1):

Официально это невозможно для IPv4. Но, на сколько мне известно, эту проблему можно решить для IPv6. Например, в комьюнити предложено [такое решение](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-additional-ipv6-addresses-to-your-droplet)